# Refactor C# foreach Loop into Linq Statement

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I have the following method containing a simple foreach loop in a C# class. The method returns the sum of totals calculated using a function on a separate class.

```
    private readonly ICalculateTotalService _calculateTotalService;

    public decimal GetTotal(IOrder order)
    {
        decimal paidTotal = 0;

        foreach (var line in order.Lines)
        {
            paidTotal += _calculateTotalService.GetTotal(line);
        }

        return paidTotal;
    }
```

Resharper is suggesting that this can be refactored into a LINQ statement.  What would the best way be to go about doing this?

Comment: You can let Resharper make the change. You should be able to click on an icon in the margin.

Comment: Let ReSharper do the change and then if you don't understand what it's done, post the original and modified code and ask why they're equivalent.

Comment: As others have said, just click the lightbulb and let it do the change for you. I will mention that it may not always be best to convert it - I've had some really clean and readable code and had ReSharper suggest converting it, so I did the suggestion and it became a jumbled and unreadable mess. You have to make the call on what is more readable. In your case I think the LINQ query will come out just as readable (if not more) than what you have now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `IOrder.Lines` is `IEnumerable` type or similar that supports LINQ:

```
private readonly ICalculateTotalService _calculateTotalService;

public decimal GetTotal(IOrder order)
{
    return order.Lines.Sum(line => _calculateTotalService.GetTotal(line));
}
```